# include tr1::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I have included `#include </usr/include/c++/4.4.3/tr1/shared_ptr.h>` in my class file,
When I attempt  to compile my class I get below error:

```
> In file included from account.h:16:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.4.3/tr1/shared_ptr.h:61:46: error: '_Lock_policy' has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.4.3/tr1/shared_ptr.h:63:30: error: expected template-name before '<' token
/usr/include/c++/4.4.3/tr1/shared_ptr.h:63:30: error: expected '{' before '<' token
/usr/include/c++/4.4.3/tr1/shared_ptr.h:63:30: error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token
/usr/include/c++/4.4.3/tr1/shared_ptr.h:89:12: error: '_Lock_policy' has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.4.3/tr1/shared_ptr.h:89:31: error: '__default_lock_policy' was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/c++/4.4.3/tr1/shared_ptr.h:100:12: error: '_Lock_policy' has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.4.3/tr1/shared_ptr.h:100:31: error: '__default_lock_policy' was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/c++/4.4.3/tr1/shared_ptr.h:209:7: error: '_Sp_counted_base' does not name a type
/usr/include/c++/4.4.3/tr1/shared_ptr.h: In constructor 'std::tr1::__shared_count<_Lp>::__shared_count()':
```

Do anyone knows what exactly could be causing this errors been thrown?

Comment: You will not be very lucky trying to compile `C++` source code with a `C` compiler ... `c` tag removed

Comment: @pmg: gcc can be used as the frontend program to compile every language the GCC suite can compile. It either finds out on its own what kind of file it is passed, or you tell it what language to compile.

Comment: @rubenvb: I didn't remove the `gcc` tag; just the `c` tag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have added `#include <tr1/memory>` and has sorted the issue.

Answer (score 5):

As of GCC 4.3, [you should use](http://anteru.net/2008/09/01/260/):

```
#include <memory>
```

... as [recommended in the gcc docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/memory.html).

Comment: +1 Thanks for the pointer! So, it seems that #include <memory> makes std::tr1::shared_ptr available in C++98-mode. Nice.